# Batch file automate

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that has options, but i wish to automate those options but i do not know which is which.

after the batch is run it then prompts for a password, which i would also like to automate from the same file. (security needs are low / not of paramount importance)

**The .bat**

> @echo off
>
> java -Xss256k -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
>   -jar BubbleUPnPTetherClient.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9

**Q. How can i find out these choice values and automate this script when executed?**

Comment: The batchfiles asks for a password?  Or the Java program which it starts asks for a password?

Comment: @Hennes the java prg asks once the batch runs.

Comment: Do you have the source for that java program?  (it is java afterall, you should be able to edit in it).  Also, is it asking a password to start using the program or is it asking for a wireless key or a code of whatever you tether to?

Comment: i have the JAR file, and it is a request from the tether control point that requests password.

Answer (score 0):

## part 1: Batch files.

The part of the batch file which you started does the following:

Open a prompt (e.g. cmd.exe) and type `mybatch.bat red white blue`.
That will start a file called 'mybatch.bat'

Inside that batch file you have access to a few variables. In our example:
%0 is mybatch.bat (the program name)
%1 is red
%2 is white
%3 is blue
%4 is empty in our example, 
...

---

## part 2: Java.

`java -Xss256k -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar BubbleUPnPTetherClient.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9`

`java` Starts the java interpreter.

This is followed by some options. E.g. `-Xss256k` , `-Djava.awt.headless=true` and `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Most of these are not interesting to us  atm.

`-jar BubbleUPnPTetherClient.jar`

Your actual java program does not do much interesting (at least not for you). It mere executes orders.  The .jar file has the ist of orders. (e.g. ask for a password, connect to some device using that password, pass tethered data along, ...'

---

## Solutions.

One of the instructions will be to ask for that password. That means you want to edit the jar file. Maybe permanently add the password to its code.

Alternatively it might accept the password as on of its input parameters. This should be in the program manual. In that case you could start it with something like this: `java -Xss256k -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar BubbleUPnPTetherClient.jar PASSWORD`

(You could also supply that password to the batchfile. That %1 things will then pass whatever you typed to the java program).

Thirdly, if neither works we are out of luck. Switch to another program or use somthing like autoIT to do things on events.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not important which option is which, because there is no given order. If you do not want to get asked for password just use the password option:

```
launch.bat -connect https://myhostname.org:58051 -login mylogin -password yourpassword
```

The documentation of all options you find at [their homepage](https://bubblesoftapps.com/bubbleupnpserver2/docs/connect_with_tether_client.html)